# Understanding simple functions applied to graphs

Tags: haskell, graph, functional-programming

I have a question about how to manipulate a function in Haskell. I have this graph:

```
import Data.Map (Map,empty,member,insert)
import Graphviz
-- | A directed graph
data Graph v = Graph
    { arcsMap :: Map v [v]     -- A map associating a vertex with its successors
    , labelMap :: Map v String -- The Graphviz label of each node
    , styleMap :: Map v String -- The Graphviz style of each node
    }deriving (Show,Eq, Ord)
```

And I have those functions

```
-- | Adds a vertex to a graph
addVertex :: Ord v => v -> Graph v -> Graph v
addVertex _ (Graph arcs labels styles)= (Graph arcs labels styles)
addVertex v (Graph arcs labels styles) = Graph (insert v [] arcs) labels styles
```

```
-- | Adds vertices to a graph
addVertices :: Ord v => Graph v -> [v] -> Graph v
addVertices (Graph arcs labels styles) [v] = map addVertex [v]
```

My problem is that I try to send all the vertices of my list to my `addVertex` function using `map`. But I do not know how to write it correctly (maybe I'm completely wrong and the map function is a very bad idea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done with a "fold" like [**`foldr :: Foldable f => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> f a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr). Indeed we can add the elements of a list of vertices (or in fact a `Foldable f => f` of items):

```
addVertices :: (Foldable f, Ord v) => Graph v -> f v -> Graph v
addVertices g0 = foldr addVertex g0
```

For a list, you can see `foldr` as a way to replace the empty list `[]` with the base element `g0`, and we replace all "cons" `(:)` with the function `addVertex` here. So that means that for a list:

```
v1 : v2 : v3 : []
```

or more verbose:

```
(:) v1 ((:) v2 ((:) v3 []))
```

we will calculate the result as:

```
addVertex v1 (addVertex v2 (addVertex v3 g0))
```

and thus each time add one vertex to the graph.

We can use [**`foldl :: Foldable f => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> f a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl) instead to pass the accumulator left-to-right:

```
addVertices :: (Foldable f, Ord v) => Graph v -> f v -> Graph v
addVertices g0 = foldl (flip addVertex) g0
```

Then we will fold the list as:

```
addVertex v3 (addVertex v2 (addVertex v1 g0))
```

Since we use a `Foldable` here, we can add the vertices in all sorts of data structures, like `Maybe v`, `[v]`, `Tree v`, etc.

We can here use an η-reduction, and implement the functions as:

```
addVertices1 :: (Foldable f, Ord v) => Graph v -> f v -> Graph v
addVertices1 = foldr addVertex

addVertices2 :: (Foldable f, Ord v) => Graph v -> f v -> Graph v
addVertices2 = foldl (flip addVertex)
```

Comment: hmmm and if I want to keep this signature ```addVertices :: Ord v => Graph v -> [v] -> Graph v``` and do the same thing with foldr? it's possible?                                       I also tried something like this: ```addVertices (Graph arcs labels styles) [v] = [addVertex x (Graph arcs labels styles) | x <- [v]]  !!  0```                                                                           In my head, it should work because it returns a graph but it does not work o_O

Comment: @VelyynS: you can simply keep the same signature, we here constructed a *more generic* signature. Using list comprehension here will not work, since it is in  essence just a mapping you made, and you do not use the graph you obtain after adding the first vertex, to add the second vertex to the graph.